# Civi 4.7.11 Update on Joomla 3.62 with receipts

Tags: joomla, 4.7, upgrade

In addition to some CkEditor issues - I am having issues when trying to print receipts  - Thoughts ?
   @import url(/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/css/civicrm.css); @import url(/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css);    Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment.  is not of type String

Answer (score 0):

-- I wanted to thank Brian S for tracking this down and hopefully he will post the fix to the core team.

It was a bug in core as a result of a recent change. The code was looking for the payment processor ID associated with the contribution. But if you have an offline contrib, there is no transaction ID or processor, and the query to do the lookup was triggering a fatal error if the value was null.

Answer (score 0):

here's the issue and PR patch:
https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19354